# Buffer Image Pixel Reader with Java

Tags: java, image, pixel, rgb

1st, I want to get each pixel RGB color then put it into some ray.
Then I want to convert each rgb color thing into a string so it would be something like this:

{{1,.5,0};{1,1,1};{1,1,1}};

{{.1,1,0};{1,.5,.5};{.2,.3,.6}};

Can anyone tell me what I need to know so I can create something like this? A Skeleton outline is much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest having a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html as a starting point. From there, you should be able to find the classes/methods that you need.

Answer (score 1):

To get the pixel RGB color and put it into an array, you need to get your data into a BufferedImage and then call `getRGB(int x, int y)`.

With the integer pixel value for the color, you can then utilize the [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class to extract individual RGB components.